# avoid sending if any field empty Axax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my form I have various fields including (input and selects) in which I want to check any empty field and prevent ajax call if any of the field is empty and focus on empty fields. so far I am trying this way, It alerts but also makes an ajax call.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert('Some fields are empty');
            return false;
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); // using this page stop being refreshing 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo site_url(''); ?>/shipment/create_shipment",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#F_id').val('');
            $('#v_id').val('');
            $('#shp_no').val('');
            $('#shipDate').val('');
            $('#sup').val('');
            $('#sup-quantity').val('');
            $('#box').val('');
            $('#box-quantity').val('');
            $("#sup").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#sup-quantity").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#box").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#box-quantity").prop('disabled', true);
            $('.alert-success').fadeOut(200).show();
            $('.alert-danger').fadeOut(200).hide();

            /// alert('form was submitted');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $('.alert-success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.alert-danger').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return false` returns from the `each` function and not the `click` function.

Try having a bool variable denoting valid, and return false if not.

```
var valid = true;
e.prevent.preventDefault(); // e being event variable in submit
$('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('Some fields are empty');
        valid = false;
        return false;
    }
});
if(!valid) return false;
//.....
```

Hope this helps.